# How to get form going to "Background state" Event in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

We have form_load event in c# forms. I want to do some job when my form1 will go in background and form2 will come to foreground. I have wasted my time in searching that, but could not found any help in this regard.

Comment: When you say "form1 will go in background and form2 will come to foreground" do you mean to say that Form 1 will lose focus and Form 2 will gain focus? Or do you mean that Form 1 will become hidden and Form 2 will be shown?

Comment: you could store a handle to the current foreground window, and and poll for  when your second form is the foreground to trigger the event or something along those lines. you can get the foreground window with the GetForegroundWindow() in user32.

Comment: Do you want this to happen when form2 opens ?

Comment: I actually need a method like form_load that will automatically called when my form go in background state or come in foreground state. For example when form loads, form_load auto called same like this i want to know Is there any such method that will auto call when my form go background state (you can say it lost focus) it call a method that may have name like form_getBackground or like so. Hope it will more clear my requirement.

Comment: Hi Jim, yes you can assume that. When form2 will open, form1 will go in background. So i want When form1 will go in background, there should be a message in console.log that form1 is in background state. and when form1 come to foreground, console.log message show that form1 came to foreground state.

Comment: Guys Thanks to all of you for your reply. I actually want to stop a timer that is on form1 and when form1 is in background state. And want to start that timer again when form1 will come to foreground state.

Comment: @Peter Duniho : You can say that it is duplicate of an existing question. But that question really didn't helped me.

Comment: Comments belong in the comments, not the post. Don't edit your post to direct a comment to a particular user, and don't format text as if it were code. If the marked duplicate does not address your question, then fix your question so that it's clear why it doesn't. Provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you've tried, and explain what _specifically_ you are having trouble getting to work. Based on your description so far, you do in fact need to handle the `Deactivated` event, which is what the marked duplicate says.

Comment: Ok . . Thankyou Peter. I appreciate your guidance and will follow it. Actually i had issue with wiring up events. Phishfordead has assisted me and now issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form.Activated Event

[DOC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activated(v=vs.110).aspx)

Occurs when the form is activated in code or by the user.

Form.Deactivate Event

[DOC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.deactivate(v=vs.110).aspx)

Occurs when the form loses focus and is no longer the active form.

UPDATE
to start and stop the timer:

```
class Form1: Form{
    void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs arg)
    {
        this.Activated += form_Activate;
        this.Deactivate += form_Deactivate;
    }

    void form_Activate(object sender, EventArgs arg){
       timer.Start();
    }

    void form_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs arg){
       timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: phishfordead. thanks for your reply. Let me have a look on DOC.

Comment: no problem, Hope I could be of some help :)

Comment: Hi phishfordead, unfortunately it didn't worked for me. These two functions are not called when i open form2. Actually form1 is behind the form2, you also can say that it has lost focus but . . , Hope you understand the situation.

Comment: did you wire up the events?

Comment: Thanks phishfordead. . . it worked.

Comment: Look at my example (under update) I wire up the events by doing this.Activated += form_Activate; this.Deactivate += form_Deactivate;

Comment: @Zeebok no problem.  I'm glad I could help.